# How to explain the tenses in these sentences?

Tags: tenses, past-participles, continuous-aspect, participial-phrases

So my Japanese student is having trouble understanding why the following tenses are used and I’m not sure how to explain it.

1. *My line manager **wants the meeting arranged** immediately.*

   Why does that use ‘arranged’ even though it hasn’t happened yet?
2. *While the stock **was being checked** the staff worked in the evenings.*

   Why does that use ‘was being checked’ and not ‘was checked’?

I know this is probably a very basic question but I’m horrible at explaining tenses to students. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. "arranged" is a contraction of "to be arranged" - which is current tense. 2. The checking & the working both took place *over a period of time* - they were not 'instant' actions.  Therefore the 'past continuous' tense is used.

Comment: If you are helping a student to learn English, you may find that our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) would suit you better - it is for teachers as well as learners!